# How to relatively place position sticky element before it becomes fixed in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

A position relative element can be positioned by using styles like

`left:50px; 
 top: 50px;`

etc, but how to position a sticky element before it acts as a fixed element ?
Using above mentioned styling is only coming into effect when the element acts like its fixed.

Comment: Position values are position values, regardless of position type.  The question (as it stands) doesn't make any sense.  Please read **[ask]** and then update the question so we can help you :)

Comment: "but a position sticky element cannot be positioned so as the positioning will come into effect only when it becomes fixed" Are you sure? Do you have a test case demonstrating this?

Comment: Indeed, it's not clear what you are trying to achieve here.